# Polymer 2.x iron-list slots and data binding

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Has anyone had any success with using a slot in an iron-list?

I can get the dom elements to show up in the slot but can't figure out how to do the data binding part. I am filling the slot with some elements that refer to the iron-list's item property with data bindings.

Example:

component-with-list:

```
<dom-module id="component-with-list">
    <template>
        <iron-list items="{{listData}}" as="item">
            <template>
                <div>
                    <div>[[item.name]]</div>
                </div>
                <slot name="listitem"></slot>
            </template>
        </iron-list>
    </template>

    <script>
        class ComponentWithList extends Polymer.Element {

            static get is() {
                return 'component-with-list'
            }

            static get properties() {
                return {
                    listData: {
                        type: Array
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        customElements.define(ComponentWithList.is, ComponentWithList);
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

use of component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./component-with-list.html">
    <title>Iron-list with a slot with bindings</title>
</head>
<body>
<dom-module id="main-document-element">
    <template>
        <h1>Iron list with a slot that has data bindings</h1>
    <component-with-list list-data="[[someData]]">
        <div slot="listitem">[[item.description]]</div>
    </component-with-list>
</template>
<script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        class MainDocumentElement extends Polymer.Element {

            static get is() { return 'main-document-element'; }

            static get properties() {
                return {
                    someData: {
                        type: Array,
                        notify: true,
                        value: function() {
                            return [
                                {
                                    name: "Item1",
                                    description: "Item Number One"
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Item2",
                                    description: "Item Number Two"
                                }
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        window.customElements.define(MainDocumentElement.is, MainDocumentElement);
    });
</script>
</dom-module>
<main-document-element></main-document-element>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`iron-list` clones the `<template>`, you *cannot* clone `<slot>`.
The exception is using `<slot>` as a template, like so:

```
<iron-list items="[[data]]">
    <slot></slot>
</iron-list>

<custom-element>
  <template>
      ...
  </template>
</custom-element>
```

Answer (score 2):

So, what you are looking to do won't work, as the slotted content will be assembled with the context of the source component.

In `main-document-element` you have:

```
    <component-with-list list-data="[[someData]]">
        <div slot="listitem">[[item.description]]</div>
    </component-with-list>
```

But the expression [[item.description]] will be evaluated within the main-document-element, rather than within the template block in the iron list.

**Long answer**

Slots are provided by a component as designated content-insertion locations. You can think of these as open cubbies, which can hold whatever an outside component places within them.

[image: Slot Illustration]

Content passed to a slot is rendered as-is by the receiving component. A component passing content featuring polymer-bindings, to a slot in another component, will actually see that content assembled with its *own* (source) context, rather than that of the receiving (destination) component.

So, for your example, since item is undefiend in `main-document-element`, it will output an empty string into the div, and pass it off to the slot in the `iron-list` template.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<dom-module id="component-with-list">
    <template>
        <iron-list items="{{listData}}" as="item">
            <slot></slot>
        </iron-list>
    </template>
    <script>...</script>
</dom-module>
```

Usage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="../../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
        <link rel="import" href="./component-with-list.html">
        <title>Iron-list with a slot with bindings</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <dom-module id="main-document-element">
          <template>
              <h1>Iron list with a slot that has data bindings</h1>
              <component-with-list list-data="[[someData]]">
                  <div>
                      <div>[[listData.name]]</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>[[listData.description]]</div>
              </component-with-list>
          </template>
          <script>...</script>
       </dom-module>
     </body>
</html>
```

I think the problem should be fix with this.