# Polymer/web components - modify shadow DOM before rendering but after light DOM distribution

Tags: shadow-dom, polymer-2.x

Does anyone know where I could hook into the element life cycle to modify some template in my component before the component renders but after the light DOM has been distributed? I guess the ready method no longer guarantees that the light DOM has been distributed when it gets called.

Comment: Some example code would be helpful so we know what you are already trying.

Comment: @Intervalia,  I don't have any code yet for this. I am trying to figure out how to modify a 'template' before it gets rendered. So far the only way I have discovered that I can do it by subclassing then overridding the getTemplate method. I was looking for an alternative. All this is to work around the fact that <slot> elements can't be cloned. I am trying to create a component where a slot is inside a repeating template which is failing because of the the slot doesn't get cloned. See  [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652369/polymer-2-x-iron-list-slots-and-data-binding).